# When is impedance matching necessary? Isn't it much less efficient on all other aspects?

Tags: rf, signal, communication, impedance-matching

I understand that discontinuities of the physical properties of conductors create reflections much like dioptres reflect a bit of light, but :

> in which cases does impedance matching become necessary to avoid that?
>   Is there a simple-ish method to decide quantitatively? (1)

My second concern (which probably stems from my limited knowledge of the topic) is about the efficiency of impedance matching:

> if all impedances including the load must be the same, doesn't that
>   mean that the overall impedance is extremely small and hence that a
>   lot of current is necessary? By "same", is it solely the amplitude or the phase shift as well? (2)

Which implies a higher voltage source because of the voltage drops, and lots of power lost as heat? Is it a tradeoff?

Let's take the following diagram as an application example.
[image]

Comment: Impedance is absolutely not the same as resistance. A "50 ohm" coaxial cable has the same impedance regardless of its length, but a (tiny) resistance that is length-dependant.

Comment: Good point, I am aware of the difference but wrote too quickly it appears. It doesn't answer the question, but your example surprises me a bit: impedances in cables are mainly inductance and resistance which are both length dependent, and the combination depends on the input frequency? I updated my question, also.

Comment: the total impedance for the system must be the same on the input and the output, if you think of it as a black box that a signal goes into and then comes out

Comment: No, that is not remotely true.

Comment: There are few rules like Tr > 2*td or Electrical length of interconnect < lamda/4  lamda is calculated based on tr of driving signal. So, if any of these things fails then that line should be considered as Transmission line to be taken care or High speed line. where impedance matching neccessary. even though it is not high speed line whenver there is an impedance mistmatch, the reflections will occur, but if those abve conditions met, the reflections will die out and will not effect the line

Comment: @user19579: could you expand in an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a while, but I think I finally understand the nature of your question.

You seem not to understand that you cannot measure a transmission line's Z0 with an Ohm meter.

A transmission line's impedance is determined by the ratio of its electric field to its magnetic field. This is determined by the line's physical dimensions, not by the materials used to build the line.

A coaxial cable's characteristic impedance, for example, is determined by the ratio of its conductor diameters and we ignore the resistance of the conductors use to build the cable (within reason). A short piece of 50 Ohm cable will typically have conductor resistance values in the micro Ohm range.

We use impedance matching in circuits when we need to improve the power transfer between 2 points in the circuit. You asked "when does impedance matching become necessary", and the answer to that depends entirely on the situation. It may be the case that a high power circuit will burn out if the magnitude of the reflection coefficient is greater than 0.2, but this amount of reflection can usually be tolerated low power circuits.

**In response to the questions below:** To research transmission line impedance, search on phrases such as microstrip, stripline, or microstrip or stripline calculator.

Here is a Wikipedia article.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip

A simple example would be if you were to drive a 2 Ohm load with a 50 Ohm source. Without impedance matching, only 15% of the power would be deliverd to the load.

You can match this load to the source with a 1/4 wave, 10 Ohm transmission line. This match will be perfect at the frequency where the transmission line is 1/4 wavelength, so 100% of the power will be delivered to the load at this particular frequency. At other frequencies, the match will be degraded.

**Response to 2nd question:**
You made 2 mistakes. First, in the calculation you made, the voltage is only 4%, but the power is proportional to V^2. But this is irrelavent because you can't calculate the power transfer this way.

Think of it this way. The impedance of a free space is 377 Ohms. If we connect an antenna to this 377 Ohm source, we don't treat the 377 Ohms as a dissipative loss point, but rather an impedance that dictating the ratio of the E and H fields, nothing more.

The correct way the calculate power transfer is to calculate Rho, the reflection coefficient. Rho = (Z0 - ZL)/(Z0 + ZL). For my example Rho = (50 - 2)/(50 + 2) = -0.923 Power transfer is 1 - Rho^2 = 14.8%

Comment: Didn't see your answer until now.. Thanks. Could you illustrate how you would improve the power transfer in a very simple example? Also, do you have a link to some reading on the topic of line impedance vs physical dimensions?

Comment: I don't understand the power transfer. I'm guessing it's much more complex than a voltage divider calculation, because for 50Ohm emitting into a 2ohm load the power transfer should be 4% (whether the drop is reactive or resistive power)?

Comment: Shame on me, calculating a voltage ratio and calling it a power transfer.. It's been a long day. I'm starting to get the hang of it thanks to the reflection coefficient, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the confusion is coming from the fact that you think each load (Z<sub>L</sub> in your picture) must also be matched to the transmission line impedance.  This is not true.

Ideally, each end of the transmission line is terminated with its characteristic impedance (Z<sub>0</sub> in your diagram).  At any point along the transmission line, you see one Z<sub>0</sub> load in each direction, for a total impedance of Z<sub>0</sub>/2.  There won't be reflections when signals get to the end of the transmission line because the terminating resistor looks electrically just like more of the same transmission line.

The the transmission line is multi-drop, then you have to be careful these connections in the middle of the line don't disturb the impedance.  Each tap therefore ideally has infinite impedance.  Since the connection from the transmission line to whatever is receiving the signal at that tap are themselves a transmission line, and that line will be terminated with infinite impedance, some of the signal can bounce back via this stub connection.  This is why such taps on impedance-controlled transmission lines are physically small.  They present a high impedance to not disturb the transmission line overall impedance, and are small so that the short connection between the transmission line and whatever is receiving the signal acts more like a lumped system as apposed to a transmission line.  Usually 1/10 of the shortest wavelength of interest is good enough.

Comment: If a transmission is used for signal transmission in only one direction, a single impedance mismatch will simply reflect energy back toward the source which won't care about it; thus, one may thus get away matching the source or the load and ignoring the other.  Matching both, however, will offer the advantage of helping the system tolerate a single mismatch at one other point.

Comment: As usual, very well explained Olin, thanks. Is there a way to know what the power transfer is to a load, so that I can determine whether impedance matching is necessary?

Comment: @Mist: It's not about total power transfer. Any mismatch between the transmission line characteristic impedance and the terminating impedances will cause reflections, which add noise to the intended signal. The issue is how much noise you can tolerate, and therefore how careful you have to be to terminate the transmisssion line properly.

Answer (score 0):

Impedance matching is not necessary. It's a solution to one particular problem, not all problems.

This was a key insight realized by Edison: you don't want impedance matching in a neighborhood power system: you aren't trying to maximize power to your customers, which you do by impedance matching: you are trying to maximize profit to your owners, which you do by minimizing the power lost in generation and transmission.

https://info.triadmagnetics.com/blog/maximum-power-theorem